# PHP sorting a set of multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array which contains another array with a distance and ID in it. I need to sort the distance part of the array, so the ID remains correlated with it's respective distance.

Eg.

```
array
(
    [0] => array(
                    [0] => 170
                    [1] => 123abc
    )
    [1] => array(
                    [0] => 150
                    [1] => 456def
    )
)
```

Now, I want to sort the distances ascending so my sorted output would look like:

```
array
(
    [0] => array(
                    [0] => 150
                    [1] => 456def
    )
    [1] => array(
                    [0] => 170
                    [1] => 123abc
    )
)
```

As 150 is smaller than 170, it has 'moved' up.

I've looked at the PHP functions for this; array_multisort() etc. however these only seem to sort the values within the arrays rather than a set of arrays.

Any help appreciated.

---

EDIT:
There isn't a fixed number of items within the first array - it ranges from 1 to infinity.

Comment: you can try `array_map()` that will sort each array inside the parent array .

Comment: Why to use `array_map` if you can simply use `usort` or `uasort`

Comment: Sorry, I should have said there can be more then two 'sets' of distance & id values. I don't think using `usort` in that case would be feasible.

Comment: @RyanVincent Sorry - yes that does work. I assumed that `usort` would only work for nested arrays. Paste here: http://pastebin.com/XwCNPaMN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
usort($yourArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a[0] - $b[0]; // index 0 is your 150 or 170
});
```